# Transfer of Ether from one party to another

Tags: web3j, address.transfer

I'm trying to transfer ETH from one account to another using web3j and a java program using following code.

```
public void transfer (String from, String to, BigInteger amount) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, IOException, CipherException{
     Credentials credentials1 = WalletUtils.loadCredentials(
            "mypassword", 
            "path\\to\\keystore");

     EthGetTransactionCount ethGetTransactionCount = web3.ethGetTransactionCount(
             from, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST).sendAsync().get();

     BigInteger nonce = ethGetTransactionCount.getTransactionCount();
     System.out.println(nonce); 

     RawTransaction rawTransaction = RawTransaction.createEtherTransaction (
             nonce, Convert.toWei("22", Convert.Unit.MWEI).toBigInteger(), Convert.toWei("44", Convert.Unit.GWEI).toBigInteger(), to, amount);
     byte[] signedMessage = TransactionEncoder.signMessage(rawTransaction, credentials1);
     String hexValue = Numeric.toHexString(signedMessage);

     EthSendTransaction ethSendTransaction = web3.ethSendRawTransaction(hexValue).sendAsync().get();
     String transactionHash = ethSendTransaction.getTransactionHash();
}
```

But I cannot get it to work. Also the nonce doesn't change and keeps returning 44.

I am running it on the Ropsten test net.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Coen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some help from the creator of web3 I was able to solve this.

Adding:

```
...
static final BigInteger GAS_PRICE = BigInteger.valueOf(20_000_000_000L);
static final BigInteger GAS_LIMIT = BigInteger.valueOf(4_300_000);
...
```

and

```
...
RawTransaction rawTransaction = RawTransaction.createEtherTransaction (
             nonce, GAS_PRICE, GAS_LIMIT, to, amount);
...
```

I managed to transfer the ether.